# Add GeoJson to Google Maps API - Uncaught not a Feature or FeatureCollection

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I try to add a GeoJson layer (generate from Postgres/PostGIS with PHP) to my Google Maps API.

For that, I've a PHP file for generating the json :

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****");
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT json_build_object('type','FeatureCollection','name','Postes techniques','crs',json_build_object('type','name','properties',json_build_object('name','urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84')),'features',(SELECT jsonb_agg(json_build_object('type','Feature','properties',json_build_object('libelle',libelle),'geometry',(ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom,4326))::json))) FROM test)) AS GeoJson");
if (!$result) {
  echo "Error";
  exit;
}
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo $row[0];
}
?>
```

The return is a very nice GeoJson who works with QGis or anything else GIS software :-)

In an other file I've a jQuery/AJAX technology for calling my PHP file, this is the extract :

```
var data = "";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'file.php',
  data: data,
    success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
    var geojson = map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}})
```

But the success is not here because I have this message:

[image]

If I try to cpoy/paste directly the GeoJson result of PHP like `var geojson = map.data.addGeoJson({Featurecollection...});` that's work !

This is an extract of my GeoJson :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -0.975467289719626,
                    0.55607476635514
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "libelle": "test 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    0.400700934579439,
                    -0.161214953271028
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "libelle": "test 2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you understand why that doesn't work?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, my GeoJson was in **string** type and the code needs **object** so I make a transformation with this manipulation `var geojson = map.data.addGeoJson(JSON.parse(data));`

That's all :-)